# Apache ServerName * wildcard not working with vhost_dbd_module

Tags: apache, vhosts, virtual-hosts, dbd, mod-vhost-alias

I'm trying to migrate my virtualhosts to a mysql database using vhost_dbd_module.

In the various examples I find online, they instruct me to use "ServerName *" as a wildcard in the VirtualHost.

When I configure my VirtualHost this way, the server just defaults back to the default DocumentRoot.  It does not query the mysql database.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # catch all other requests that don't get caught above
        ServerName *
        # fallbackDocumentRoot in case mysql server is down
        DocumentRoot /var/html/404

        DBDriver mysql
        DBDParams "host=<hostname> user=<user> dbname=<dbname>"
        DBDocRoot "SELECT documentRoot FROM virtualhosts WHERE serverName = %s" HOSTNAME
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when I change it to this (specify the ServerName to domain.tld), it works properly (queries the database for domain.tld and returns the proper documentroot for domain.tld)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # catch all other requests that don't get caught above
        ServerName domain.tld
        # fallbackDocumentRoot in case mysql server is down
        DocumentRoot /var/html/404

        DBDriver mysql
        DBDParams "host=<hostname> user=<user> dbname=<dbname>"
        DBDocRoot "SELECT documentRoot FROM virtualhosts WHERE serverName = %s" HOSTNAME
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas what is misconfigured?

Answer (score 0):

After messing around some more, it appears that ServerName * only works when it is the FIRST VirtualHost in the system.

I moved it first in order, with a few other virtualhosts beneath it (with more specific ServerName example.tld) and both the DB hosts and the statically configured hosts worked.